# How can I specify the type of a parameter when the object type is from a web service?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a PowerShell module.  I have a Get-MyPerson function which accepts an Identity parameter, calls a web service and returns an object of type PERSON (the return type from the web service).

I'm now working on a Set-MyPerson object to update a couple of properties.  What I want to be able to do is:

```
Set-MyPerson 1234 -GolfHandicap 22
Get-MyPerson JDoe | Set-MyPerson -GolfHandicap 22
```

(the latter following Get-ADUser | Set-ADUser usage)

This requires Set-MyPerson to accept a parameter of type string for the former and a parameter of type Person for the latter, using parameter sets to distinguish.

I have the basic functionality working for a string but am struggling with the parameter for Person objects.

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Person",Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[PERSON]$Person,
```

won't work because PowerShell doesn't recognize PERSON (as expected):

> Set-MyPerson : Unable to find type [PERSON]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

How can I get PowerShell to recognize my PERSON class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try with `[object]` or `[psbject]` ?

Comment: Both [object] and [psobject] worked.  Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: I would use psObject, but with no real reason.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution, which came to me in a moment of echoey isolation, was rather more hassle than @JPBlanc's:

I used the WSDL command to generate a CSharp file:

```
wsdl http://server.dns.name/webservice/path/service?wsdl
```

Then I used the CSharp command-line compiler to create an assembly:

```
csc /target:library PersonService.cs
```

which created a DLL called PersonService.dll.

And then used:

```
$assemblyPath = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PersonModule\PersonService.dll"
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
```

to load it.